# Forms & inputs in amp-html

Tags: forms, input, amp-html

What if I decided to create whole website / webapp with AMP-HTML,
how should I create forms (login, etc), if all input elements are prohibited in specification ( https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this stage, it isn't likely you'd have AMP pages exclusively on a site like that. One way to get non-amp type stuff on a page is [amp-iframe](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-iframe/amp-iframe.md)

Answer (score 0):

Form inputs are not prohibited. You can easily adopt your forms to AMP. The amp-iframe should be your go-to when no AMP component fits your needs.

See https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form

Where exactly are you running into problems?